# Change zoom of selected item for browsefragment in android tv

Tags: android, menuitem, selected, television, leanback

I want to change the zoom value of selected element for BrowseFragment of TV elements.
Is it possible? or that zoom os hardcoded in browsefragment?

Comment: Any luck ?? Have You done ?

Comment: I have done .. I will share the answer.

Comment: @MuhammadAdil i need similiar implementation. Can you please share your code ?

Comment: Sure, I will make a public repo of the code I have done so other people can get benefits.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how you can change zoom factor of the card. In your MainFragment/RowsFragment you must be using ListRowPresenter. You can initialise it this way.

```
ListRowPresenter presenter= new ListRowPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_LARGE,true);
```

here you can change FocusHighlight Factor you will find many other values or you can choose any per according to your requirements. Here are those values.

**ZOOM_FACTOR_MEDIUM** , 
**ZOOM_FACTOR_SMALL** , 
**ZOOM_FACTOR_XSMALL** , 
**ZOOM_FACTOR_NONE**

if you pass **false** in second parameter then you can remove dim light effect on all grids. You can just play around.Here are some other possible functions you can use

```
    presenter.setShadowEnabled(false);
    presenter.enableChildRoundedCorners(false);
    presenter.setSelectEffectEnabled(false);
    presenter.setKeepChildForeground(false);
```

these are by default **true** in the library.

if you want to customise design of leanback's **RowsFragment** or **BrowseFragment** then just grab it's **XML** file and you can play around with its design. You can put your own implementation. This is just an idea to that how you can also customise other fragments of leanback.

Here is the layout of **RowsFragment** I have changed some colours so you can understand please save it in your layouts under res directory with this name "**lb_rows_fragment.xml**", don't forget to name it as I have said.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/descriptions_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/main_screen_prog_desc_height"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/description_parent_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/main_screen_prog_desc_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
<!--you can add description etc here or any other stuff. whatever you like. -->
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ScaleFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/scale_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/descriptions_layout"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_marginRight="170dp">

    <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView
        android:id="@+id/container_list"
        style="?attr/rowsVerticalGridStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#45f"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ScaleFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can change zoom factor of the card:

One way is above mention the answer: using zoom factor

```
 val listRowPresenter = ListRowPresenter(ZOOM_FACTOR_LARGE)
```

Second way is to change the fraction value of ZOOM_FACTOR from the dimen.xml file.

Here is default fraction value for all, you can customize based on your need

```
<item name="lb_focus_zoom_factor_xsmall" type="fraction">106%</item>
<item name="lb_focus_zoom_factor_small" type="fraction">110%</item>
<item name="lb_focus_zoom_factor_medium" type="fraction">114%</item>
<item name="lb_focus_zoom_factor_large" type="fraction">118%</item>
```